# angular jsonp factory doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I have this factory in angular, and its returning me a 0 error code always, even tho i can see it fetches from the json origin, can someone help me?

```
app.factory('docFactory', function($http) {  
  var docFactory = {      
    async: function(page) {
      var url = 'http://example.com/ProviderRequest?&queryString=searchv2&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';     
        var promise = $http.jsonp(url).error(function (response, status) {
          alert(status);
        }).success(function (response, status) {
          alert(status);
        }).then(function (response, status) {
          return response.data;           
      });
      return promise;
    }};
  return docFactory;
});
```

Comment: You do know JSONP returns a function right?

Comment: jsonp(url, config)

Shortcut method to perform JSONP request.

Parameters
url – {string} – Relative or absolute URL specifying the destination of the request. Should contain JSON_CALLBACK string.
config(optional) – {Object=} – Optional configuration object
Returns
{HttpPromise} – Future object

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code.  The url is just not returning anything.  Try a url you know will return jsonp.

Comment: use this url:  `https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola?callback=JSON_CALLBACK`

Comment: [Here's a plunk](http://plunker.co/edit/BolqDWDgdQoj2XRlC6Sd?p=preview) with the facebook jsonp return.

Comment: i cant understand why like this it doesn´t work:
http://plunker.co/edit/xQVBchTYOro1CB979021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this myself.  If your JSONP is a function call or something falsy (`null`, `false`, `undefined`) you will encounter this behavior.  Take a look at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/httpBackend.js#L48) code from AngularJS HTTP backend for more info (lines 41 - 54 are relevant).

If you are returning a function, you might just need to return true or something after the call.

**Edit**: After looking at your plunker it seems that your JSONP response is not calling the callback method.  The response should be `angular.callbacks._0( { ... } );` where `{ ... }` is your object, and `angular.callbacks._0` is the value of the `callback` query parameter in the request.

Answer (score -1):

Your example above is almost right. Just change the `callback` parameter to

```
jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

You should have something like that at the end

```
$http.jsonp(url + '?jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
})
```