# Angular JSONP Factory call not working, however it does work in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have looked at every post on SO related to this issue but still cannot find the answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906582/angular-jsonp-factory-doesnt-work) response appeared to be the most promising but I didn't understand the answer, and it appears the person who asked did not either.

What am I trying to do?
Make a JSONP angular `GET` request to the itunes API. This works perfectly when I make the `GET` request from my controller, however when I tried to refactor, in order to obey the principle of 'Separation of Concerns' by moving this request into a factory, and injecting into the controller I am running into difficulties. I know the call is still being made as I am getting a CORS error if I do not use a JSONP call in my factory.

Here is the factory code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('jDillaApp', []).factory('Music', function ($http) {

var o = {
    songs: []
};

o.getNextSongs = function () {
    return $http.jsonp({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=j+dilla&limit=25?format=jsonp&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
}

return o
})
```

My controller looks like this:

```
myApp.controller('jDillaCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'Music',

function ($scope, $http, Music) {

    Music.getNextSongs();
    $scope.songs = Music.songs;
    var media = new Audio();

    $scope.playSong = function () {
        media.pause();
        var randomSong = Math.round(Math.random() * ($scope.songs.length - 1));
        media = new Audio($scope.songs[randomSong]);
        media.play();
    }

}]);
```

The error is not a lot of help as far as I can tell but worth posting anyway `TypeError: h.replace is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `$http.jsonp` method has wrong inputs that was your first problem, `$http.jsonp` method accepts two parameter as such

> $http.jsonp(url, [config]) 
>   url -> the url which you want make an ajax
>   config -> if you want to make additional changes in request then you can pass those setting from here in `{}` key value pair like you can set `headers`, `type`, etc.

Your service method should return promise, as you only need to return `$http.jsonp` object which already has promise, no need of creating extra promise object here.

**Service**

```
o.getNextSongs = function () {
    return $http.jsonp('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=j+dilla&limit=25?format=jsonp&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
}
```

In controller that call will be resolved using `.success` & `.error` also you can use `.then`

**Controller**

```
Music.getNextSongs()
.success(function (data) {
     //here you get the ajax success
     console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: hmmmm, I am still seeing the same error :-( When I have done this in past, not using JSONP I made the full ```GET``` request in the factory (which may also be bad practice)

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald  look at my edit..json method should have only url parameter, second param is optional where we can have configuration for jsonp

Comment: @pankajparker fantastic, that worked. Would you mind giving a small bit more of an explanation as to why this is the case, both in order to help me understand, and for the next person who comes along. Is it because it is a JSONP request?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald I've added explanation how it was failing & how does I fixed..now could you please do upvote & accept answer..That would be nice then